# How to remove empty query params using URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, url-parameters

I was working with query params, and got introduced to [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams). I am using it to form this kind of object to query,

```js
const x = {
  a: 'hello World'
  b: 23
  c: ''
}
let params = new URLSearchParams(x);
console.log(params.toString()) // a=hello+World&b=23&c=
```

Here, I dont want to have that `c=`, as it's ugly, and my API doesn't need that.

So, I want this result `a=hello+World&b=23` (without empty query string)
But, I couldn't find anything on the MDN Web Docs.

How am I supposed to do that?

Doing the following doesn't work, as it seems to directly mutate the `params` which affects the `forEach`:

```js
const x = {
  a: 'hello World',
  b: '',
  c: ''
};

let params = new URLSearchParams(x);
params.forEach((value, key) => { // never reaches `c`
  console.log(key, ' => ', value)
  if (value == '')
    params.delete(key);
});
console.log(params.toString());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can iterate over the key-value pair and delete the keys with `null` values:

```js
const x = {
  a: 'hello World',
  b: '',
  c: ''
};

let params = new URLSearchParams(x);
let keysForDel = [];
params.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (value == '') {
    keysForDel.push(key);
  }
});

keysForDel.forEach(key => {
  params.delete(key);
});

console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: just be aware this will remove `0` values as well

Comment: @Matt changing the condition to `v == ''` will do, Right ??

Comment: I changed as per that

Comment: @RahulBhobe got another little problem will u help ??

Comment: sure - what's up?

Comment: i originally had taken care of it. then it worked and i was surprised

Comment: @RahulBhobe you awesome!

Comment: I can't believe this is not part of the URLSearchParams API. I can't believe this is the canonical solution. I just can't.

Answer (score 7):

A clean way I do it myself is as follows (using lodash):

```js
import omitBy from 'lodash/omitBy';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

const x = {
  a: 'hello World'
  b: 23
  c: ''
}

const params = new URLSearchParams(omitBy(x, isEmpty));

// mixing other sets
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  otherParam: 'foo', 
  ...omitBy(x, isEmpty)
});
```

Comment: This will remove 0 values as well.

Comment: I would go with `isNil` over `isEmpty` for the reason that @Tonni has mentioned above.

Comment: I used `isNil` with `omitBy`, and everything went well

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to delete useless params from query in JavaScript ES5+:

```
for (let param in query) { /* You can get copy by spreading {...query} */
  if (query[param] === undefined /* In case of undefined assignment */
    || query[param] === null 
    || query[param] === ""
  ) {    
    delete query[param];
  }
}
return new URLSearchParams(query).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another clean way you can do this:

```
const x = {
  a: 'hello World',
  b: 23,
  c: ''
};

// Create a new object with only non-empty properties
const y = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(x).filter(([key, value]) => value !== '')
);

// Then use this new object to create URLSearchParams
let params = new URLSearchParams(y);

console.log(params.toString());  // a=hello+World&b=23
```

1. `Object.entries(x)` gives us an array of [key, value] pairs for the x object.
2. The filter function is used to remove entries where the value is an empty string ('').
3. `Object.fromEntries` then takes this filtered array and turns it back into an object.
4. This resulting object is passed to `URLSearchParams`, which will only have the entries with non-empty values.

Answer (score 1):

In case your are working with the query as a string you can also filter it with a regex :

```js
const query = "a=hello+World&b=23&c=&d=12&e="

query.replace(/\w+=&/g, '').replace(/&\w+=$/, '')
// "a=hello+World&b=23&d=12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that preserves any 0 values:

```js
const x = {
  a: 'hello World',
  b: '',
  c: '',
  d: 0
};

const params = new URLSearchParams(new URLSearchParams(x).toString().replace(/(?:\&|^)[^\&]*?\=(?=\&|$)/g, ''));

console.log(params.toString());
```

If you want something a bit easier to follow:

```js
const x = {
  a: 'hello World',
  b: '',
  c: '',
  d: 0
};

const params = new URLSearchParams(new URLSearchParams(x).toString().split('&').filter(el => el.split('=').slice(-1) !== '').join('&')).toString();

console.log(params.toString());
```